# 2.8 crashes when choosing "quick explode"

Tags: objects, meta-objects

I was wandering if anyone has the same issue and can it be fixed. In the drop down objects box choosing Quick effects then quick explode it is closing the blender down. However I have checked all other quick effects with no problems. Can anyone share any light please?

Comment: yes it crashes every time but not on fur smoke or fluid! when i choose explode it just shuts down.